# Newman - getting same test run result json as in manual Postman export

Tags: json, automated-tests, postman, postman-collection-runner

when I finish a manual run of collection in Postman I get test run results in this format:

```
{
    "id": "f1280278-4ec5-44d9-97b3-77d20e74b730",
    "name": "Things Newman",
    "timestamp": "2021-05-30T13:04:28.772Z",
    "collection_id": "01f79316-8ddc-4d06-a8d4-5a9a315a67ee",
    "folder_id": 0,
    "environment_id": "ab5c0adb-d80c-482f-a21a-8c5078696aae",
    "totalPass": 58,
    "totalFail": 18,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "2d403678-d0d6-4295-8cb2-a189bc0d6a5f",
            "name": "utility_get_access_token",
            "url": "https://blablabla/token",
            "time": 293,
            "responseCode": {
                "code": 200,
                "name": "OK"
            }, ...
```

I fail to get same results with newman:

```
newman run collections/things.postman_collection.json --environment environments/things_DEV.postman_environment.json -r json,html --reporter-json-export output.json –-reporter-html-export Reports.html --disable-unicode --color off
```

I get it in a different format:

```
{
  "collection": {
    "_": {
      "postman_id": "01f79316-8ddc-4d06-a8d4-5a9a315a67ee"
    },
    "item": [
      {
        "id": "1b6d3a2b-013c-4fae-8b65-fbe21606d141",
        "name": "api/v1/retail-lending",
        "item": [
          {
            "id": "a40a69a4-a12d-496a-b254-ea9dd2fa95d1",
            "name": "utility_get_access_token",
            "request": {
              "url": {
                "path": [
                  "auth",
                  "realms",
                  "internal",
                  "protocol",
                  "openid-connect",
                  "token"
                ],
```

Obviously not showing if test passed or failed easily, which makes my life a bit harder trying to parse it.

How do I programatically get same results with newman as I can with manually exporting collection test results from Postman?

Comment: https://medium.com/younited-tech-blog/generate-automated-test-reports-using-postman-b9c8cd53b955

Comment: better you raise a feature request in postman github

Comment: @matt But this created only html version